# GPS Tracker Connection Error

Tags: java, gps, netty, tracker

I am currently trying to implement a simple communication module between a server and GPS trackers (GT02 - GT06) . Using JBoss Netty , but for some reasons I cant keep the connection open for too long with the trackers. It seems to drop after a few seconds of sending the first stream of data.

Also Does anyone have an idea how I can manage the GT06 device ? It keeps sending a different Session key everytime it connects , making it hard to relate to the IMEI.

Thanks for your help ! It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable tcp keep alives in netty. See [1].

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/SocketChannelConfig.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)